# JPA/Hibernate: JPA Relationship, filter NULL values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've been looking around Google for a while without finding an answer.

I have two tables: one is mine, the other is shared. Mapping to entities, I have this very generic situation:

```
Entity1 {
  @Id Long id;
  Long otherId;
  Entity2 other;
  ...
}

Entity2 {
 @Id Long id;
 Long otherId;
 Date invalidatingDate;
 ...
}
```

Those two otherId are the same and should be joined but due to field invalidatingDate I get a OneToMany relationship that should be OneToOne. Is there any way to costrain the relation with a INVALIDATING_DATE IS NULL? Into Entity2, given an otherId, a WHERE INVALIDATING_DATE IS NULL will always give a single result.
Is such a thing possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using hibernate, you can do the following (I wasn't sure what is the relation from your question - `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`, but pay attention to the `@Where` anootation):

```
Entity1 {
  @Id Long id;
  Long otherId;

  @ManyToOne/@OneToOne
  @Where(clause = "invalidatingDate = NULL")
  Entity2 other;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shay. I didn't know about the @Where annotation, I searched for where as annotation attribute... tomorrow I'll try it.
The true relationship is a OneToMany because of the invalidatingDate which is scheduled to be set at a given delay but it's not sure a new valid will be inserted. That's why I need just those with invalidatingDate to NULL. Without it, the relationship is OneToOne.

Comment: Sorry @shay-elkayam I had hard work last week. No it didn't, we "solved" creating a filtered view and linking the entity to it.
thank you anyway